# Preserve the size of the svg group when changing the canvas size

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have an svg graph with a legend. When the graph is resized, the legend stretches:

[image]

[image]

However, I would like the legend to have a constant size and not to be affected by svg resizing. 
The legend is a group with attached circle and text elements. Maybe I could append a new group when the canvas is resized? Does anyone know a good solution?

Answer (score 1):

Would it not be easier to have two separate svgs (graph and legend) in a container div and set the graph to 100% width and the legend to a fixed width in CSS?

Comment: True, it would work but I thought that there may be another easier way. I'll definitely try it.Thank you!